# C++ OpenCv : Stitching more than 2 images

Tags: c++, opencv, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

I'm trying to stitch images together with a code i found on the internet

```
void main()
{
  vector <Mat> vImg;
  Mat rImg;


  vImg.push_back(imread("PATH IMG 1"));
  vImg.push_back(imread("PATH IMG 2"));
  vImg.push_back(imread("PATH IMG 3"));

  imshow("0",vImg[0]);
  imshow("1",vImg[1]);
  imshow("2",vImg[2]);



  Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault();



  Stitcher :: Status status = stitcher.stitch(vImg,rImg);


    imshow("Stitching Result", rImg);



  waitKey(0);

}
```

The code works fine with 2 images but fails when I include a third one. The error message is : "Unhandled exception at 0x51b4dcaa in testStiching.exe : 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004"

I am sure the path to my images is correct (imread works fine) and my images are similar in dimension,...

I have already searched for a solution but either nobody reply to the guy who asks or their solution doesn't apply to my situation.

Thank you for your help

EDIT : Here's the source I used for the code and the images

http://study.marearts.com/2013/11/opencv-stitching-example-stitcher-class.html

Comment: does it work with any combination of 2 images? So 1+2; 1+3 and 2+3? Or does it fail with any of those combinations?

Comment: It works with 1+2, 2+3 but fails with 1+3 ( and of course the correct order is 1,2,3). The error message is similar but the locations are different

Comment: can you try the order 3;2;1?

Comment: Does the access violation happen in the stitching process or in cv::imshow?

Comment: 3,2,1 also fails.   I commented the imshow for the result and it still fails

Comment: I've tested and the code above works fine with 3 images. So the problem it is not in the code. Is it possible for you to upload the images?

Comment: I put the link of the website with the code and the images

Comment: Tested with S1.jpg, S2.jpg and S3.jpg and worked well. Could you test with the same three images?
You should print the `status` value ([doc here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d2/d8d/classcv_1_1Stitcher.html#a507409ce9435dd89857469d12ec06b45)). `0` value means that the stiching is made succesfully. However if `1` or `ERR_NEED_MORE_IMGS` is returned, no image is created and the last imshow will fail as there is no image created in `rImg`.

Comment: I can't print status when I use 3 images because the error occurs at the line "Stitcher :: Status status = stitcher.stitch(vImg,rImg);".

With 2 images, status is of course equal to 0